Can synchronized watches be internally calibrated to adjust for acceleration?
If you had two atomic watches, could you incorporate an accelerometer into them that could adjust for time dilation and keep them synchronized as they moved into different inertial frames and back into the same one?

Yes. They could remain synchronized in any one selected reference frame, provided you knew their initial position and velocity in that frame as well as the metric throughout that frame.
Of course, small uncertainties in any of those quantities may cause large uncertainties in the synchronization, depending on the details.
